# Why won't this insert query work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I am very new in **Microsoft SQL Server** and I have the following problem.

On a database I have a very big table named **VulnerabilityAlertDocument** and I have to do an insert on this table.

So I have created the following insert query:

```
INSERT INTO VulnerabilityAlertDocument (
            [Id], [VulnerabilityAlertId], [SourceId], [BugTraqID], [Title], 
            [StatusID], [CVE], [Published], [LastUpdated], [Remote],[Local],
            [Credibility],[Classification],[Availability], [Ease], [Authentication], 
            [CVSS2_BaseScore], [CVSS2_TemporalScore], [CVSS2_BaseVector], 
            [CVSS2_TemporalVector], [CVSS1_BaseScore], [CVSS1_TemporalScore], 
            [NVD_CVSS2_BaseScore], [NVD_CVSS2_ComponentString], [ImpactRating], 
            [Severity], [EaseofExploit], [UrgencyRating], [LastChange], 
            [ShortSummary], [Impact], [TechnicalDescription], [AttackScenario], 
            [Exploit], [Credit], [URL], [AlertStatusId], [Type], [DetailLevel], 
            [Language], [dd]
     VALUES ('10000', '10000', 'TEST', '12345', 'TEST TITLE', '46967', 'TEST CVE', 
             '2010-12-19 00:00:00.000', '2011-06-29 20:49:07.000', 'Yes','No', 
             'Vendor Confirmed', 'Boundary Condition Error', 'Always', 
             'No Exploit Available', 'Not Required', 'N.A.', 'N.A.', 'N.A.', 'N.A.' 
             'N.A.', 'N.A.', 'N.A.', 'N.A.', '6', '7,8', '0', '6,8', 'N.A.', 
             'TEST SHORT SUMMARY', 'TEST IMPACT', 'TEST TECHNICAL DESCRIPTION', 
             'TEST ATTACK SCENARIO', 'TEST EXPLOIT', 'TEST CREDIT', '46967', '-1', 
             '-1', '-1', 'NULL');
```

I followed the syntax as shown here: http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms174633.aspx

But it doesn't work. When I execute that `INSERT` command I obtain the following message error:

> **Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword**
>   **'VALUES'.**

Why? What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: You are missing the closing paren at the end of your column list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing closing parenthisis `)` just before `VALUES`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
INSERT INTO VulnerabilityAlertDocument ([Id], [VulnerabilityAlertId], [SourceId], [BugTraqID], [Title], [StatusID], [CVE], [Published], [LastUpdated], [Remote], [Local], [Credibility], [Classification], [Availability], [Ease], [Authentication], [CVSS2_BaseScore], [CVSS2_TemporalScore], [CVSS2_BaseVector], [CVSS2_TemporalVector], [CVSS1_BaseScore], [CVSS1_TemporalScore], [NVD_CVSS2_BaseScore], [NVD_CVSS2_ComponentString], [ImpactRating], [Severity], [EaseofExploit], [UrgencyRating], [LastChange], [ShortSummary], [Impact], [TechnicalDescription], [AttackScenario], [Exploit], [Credit], [URL], [AlertStatusId], [Type], [DetailLevel], [Language], [dd])
VALUES('10000', '10000', 'TEST', '12345', 'TEST TITLE', '46967', 'TEST CVE', '2010-12-19 00:00:00.000', '2011-06-29 20:49:07.000', 'Yes', 'No', 'Vendor Confirmed', 'Boundary Condition Error', 'Always', 'No Exploit Available', 'Not Required', 'N.A.', 'N.A.', 'N.A.', 'N.A.' 'N.A.', 'N.A.', 'N.A.', 'N.A.', '6', '7,8', '0', '6,8', 'N.A.', 'TEST SHORT SUMMARY', 'TEST IMPACT', 'TEST TECHNICAL DESCRIPTION', 'TEST ATTACK SCENARIO', 'TEST EXPLOIT', 'TEST CREDIT', '46967', '-1', '-1', '-1', 'NULL');
```